# jQuery change doesn't work in bootstrap 5 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I add an `input` form in `bootstrap 5` tabs like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <ul class="nav bg-dark">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-secondary" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-secondary" id="about-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#about" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-secondary active" id="album-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#album" href="#">ALBUM</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x300/?text=home" />
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x300/?text=about" />
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="album" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="album-tab">
          <input id="searchDateFrom" type="text" class="form-control search-by-date" data-name="searchDateFrom">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x300/?text=album" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var dateFrom = $('#searchDateFrom').val();
$('#searchDateFrom').change(function() {
  console.log(dateFrom);
});
```

Now, In action, I need to get input value using jQuery `change` method. But, after change the value I can't see any result. (`into console log` in case)

How do can I fix this problem?!

DEMO [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v6wyhzgu/)

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't refresh the value of your variable "dateFrom" on change.

dateFrom keeps its initial value, which is "". On change, it logs this value.

You should change your code to:

```
var dateFrom;
$('#searchDateFrom').change(function() {
  dateFrom = $('#searchDateFrom').val();
  console.log(dateFrom);
});
```

This will update the value of the variable on change and log it afterwards.